# Torsion elements of special linear group over $\mathbb{F}_q[[T]]$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}_q[[T]]$ be the ring of formal power series over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ of characteristic $p>2$ and ${\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q[[T]])$ the special linear group over $\mathbb{F}_q[[T]]$ for some positive integer $n\geq 2$.

**Question:** Denote by $T({\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q[[T]]))$ the set of torsion elements in ${\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q[[T]])$. Is $T({\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q[[T]]))$ a group? Is it true that $T({\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q[[T]]))={\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint $$\pmatrix{0&-a\\ a^{-1} & 0}\pmatrix{0&-a^2\\ a^{-2} & 0}= \pmatrix{-a^{-1}&0\\0& -a}$$

Comment: For example, just take $a=1+T$. This gives a counterexample. Thanks.